# Datagrid Not updating Index

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have this data grid with some data and When I click in one button it's supposed to move the row up or down(depends on the button), the problem that i'm facing is. When i click to move, lets say down, the first index goes to index 2 and the index 2 goes to index 1, and the UI shows the updated list, but when i click on the first row, the second row gets selected the same happens if, I click the second row the first one gets selected. Below is my code:

*data grid:*

```
         <dg:DataGrid x:Name="data_grid"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding obs_plano_descarga}"                   
                     SelectionEnabled="True"
                     RowHeight="50"
                     HeaderHeight="30"
                     BorderColor="#CCCCCC"
                     HeaderBackground="#5963f7"
                     ActiveRowColor="#8899AA" ItemSelected="Data_grid_ItemSelected"
                     Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                    <dg:DataGrid.Resources>
                        <ResourceDictionary>
                            <conv:data_grid_converter x:Key="StreakToColorConverter" />
                        </ResourceDictionary>
                    </dg:DataGrid.Resources>
                    <dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
                        <dg:PaletteCollection>
                            <Color>#F2F2F2</Color>
                            <Color>#FFFFFF</Color>
                        </dg:PaletteCollection>
                    </dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
                    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>

                        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Comp."
                                           PropertyName="compartimento"
                                           Width="2*"
                                           VerticalContentAlignment="CenterAndExpand"
                                           HorizontalContentAlignment="CenterAndExpand" />

                        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Prod"
                                           PropertyName="codigo_produto"
                                           Width="2*"
                                           VerticalContentAlignment="CenterAndExpand"
                                           HorizontalContentAlignment="CenterAndExpand" />

                        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Volume"
                                           PropertyName="volume"
                                           Width="3*"
                                           VerticalContentAlignment="CenterAndExpand"
                                           HorizontalContentAlignment="CenterAndExpand" />

                        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Posto"
                                           PropertyName="descricao_posto"
                                           Width="5*"
                                           VerticalContentAlignment="CenterAndExpand"
                                           HorizontalContentAlignment="CenterAndExpand" />

                        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="tqe"
                                           PropertyName="seq_tanque"
                                           Width="2*"
                                           VerticalContentAlignment="CenterAndExpand"
                                           HorizontalContentAlignment="CenterAndExpand" />
                    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
                </dg:DataGrid>
```

*ItemSelected: *

```
  private void Data_grid_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            plano_select = (plano_carga_descarga)e.SelectedItem;
            index = e.SelectedItemIndex;
        }
```

move row to the next index:

```
 private void Tap_baixo_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lista_plano.AddRange(view_model_plano_descarga.local_plano_descarga);
            if (plano_select != null && index > -1)
            {
                var index_plano = lista_plano.IndexOf(plano_select);
                lista_plano.Remove(plano_select);
                lista_plano.Insert(index_plano + 1, plano_select);
                data_grid.SelectedItem = null;
                BindingContext = new view_model_plano_descarga(lista_plano);
            }
        }
```

view_model:

```
 public view_model_plano_descarga(List<plano_carga_descarga> plano)
        {
            if (plano != null)
            {
                obs_plano_descarga.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < plano.Count; i++)
                {
                    local_plano_descarga.Add(plano[i]);
                }
                local_dados_motorista.Add(local_plano_descarga[0]);
                model_turno turno = new model_turno();
                turno.muda_background(local_plano_descarga[0].turno);
            }
        }

        public static ObservableCollection<plano_carga_descarga> local_plano_descarga = new ObservableCollection<plano_carga_descarga>();

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
```

Comment: What is `lista_plano`? It's never declared and it's seen in only one method. What you should do is bind ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection, once. Then move items around in the ObservableCollection using the ObservableCollection's methods to do that. The UI will update properly.

Comment: I tried using `ObservableCollection<T>.Move()`, but the same think happens in the UI the list order changes, ( the first row goes to second row and second row goes to first row) but the same thing happens. When I click in the second Row, the first one gets selected in the UI.

Comment: 999,999 times out of a million, the bug is not in ObservableCollection or any other framework code. It's in your own logic.

Comment: P.S. What about `lista_plano`?

Comment: `lista_plano ` its a List<T> that I created to hold the information.  then I send its data to the observableCollection.

Comment: @MarioSegalla I check the logic in your code, but I do not understand it well, could you provide the code sample for us to test?